# Android Studio: не помещается RecyclerView в NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, nested-scrollview

Не помещаются все элементы RecyclerView в NestedScrollView. Привожу картинку в качестве примера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элементы RecyclerView #2 просто не влезают по высоте в NestedScrollView. Не могу понять - почему. Код разметки у меня сейчас выглядит следующим образом:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/some_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/firstHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HEADER #1"
                android:textSize = "20sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/firstRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstHeader"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secondHeader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HEADER #2"
                android:textSize = "20sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/secondRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondHeader"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить атрибут nestedScrollingEnabled=ffalse в в  android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" и выставьте ему match_parent. Но по-хорошему лучше использовать один список и разные вью тайпы